# Which closure implementation is faster between two examples

Tags: performance, groovy, closures

I'm writing some training material for the Groovy language and I'm preparing an example which would explain Closures.
The example is a simple caching closure for "expensive" methods, `withCache`

```
def expensiveMethod( Long a ) {
    withCache (a) {
        sleep(rnd())
        a*5
    }
}
```

So, now my question is: which of the two following implementations would be the fastest and more idiomatic in Groovy?

```
 def withCache = {key, Closure operation ->

    if (!cacheMap.containsKey(key)) {
        cacheMap.put(key, operation())
    }
    cacheMap.get(key)
 }
```

or

```
def withCache = {key, Closure operation ->
    def cached = cacheMap.get(key)
    if (cached) return cached
    def res = operation()
    cacheMap.put(key, res)
    res
}
```

I prefer the first example, as it doesn't use any variable but I wonder if accessing the `get` method of the `Map` is slower than returning the variable containing the computed result.

Obviously the answer is "it depends on the size of the `Map`" but, out of curiosity, I would like to have the opinion of the community.

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you also use memoize? http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/groovy-goodness-cache-closure-results.html

Comment: yes, but it's a bit advanced for introducing closures. This question is actually a personal curiosity that would apply to Java too.

Comment: There's almost no way it can be matter, unless this is an operation that is being performed thousands of times a second.  HashMap *lookup* is usually an [O(1) operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_o_notation#Orders_of_common_functions), which is the *worst* place to worry about performance optimization.

Comment: I'm absolutely against premature opt. As I said this is basically slide-ware, that is code that will appear on slides, not on any real environment. My question was more related to the most idiomatic way to express the code in Groovy and, as I was at it, a performance consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I agree with OverZealous, that worrying about two get operations is a premature optimization. The second exmaple is also not equal to the first. The first allows null for example, while the second on uses Groovy-Truth in the if, which means that null evals to false, as does for example an empty list/array/map. So if you want to show calling Closure I would go with the first one. If you want something more idiomatic I would do this instead for your case:

```
def expensiveMethod( Long a ) {
    sleep(rnd())
    a*5
}
def cache = [:].withDefault this.&expensiveMethod
```

Comment: Hi @blackdrag, I'm not sure I get your example fully. The .withDefault method decorates a map with the default behavior for a null ".get" operation, which in this case would be calling "expensiveMethod". But in my example, I want to use the "withCache" Closure to be able to use the cache on  as many methods as I like. Makes sense?

Comment: It is a question of letting the method do the caching (your way) or provide an outside way. You can of course use other Closures and methods in my example as well. The most idiomatic way would be imho:
   def expensiveMethod(Long a){
     sleep(rnd())
     a*5
   }
   def handle = this.&expensiveMethod.memoize()

Available since Groovy 1.8: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+1.8+release+notes#Groovy18releasenotes-Closurememoization

It very much depends on what you want to show in the end